# Firebase (Swift) - generate unique ID with numbers only?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Right now, I'm generating unique IDs with `childByAutoId()`, but was wondering if there was a way to do this only generating numbers, no letters or other characters?

The reason is I need to be able to automatically send this key through imessage (part of how I send invites) and when it contains letters you're not able to automatically select and copy the key without copying the entire text message. With numbers only the key will be underlined and selectable.

Is there a way to either generate an ID with numbers only, or to selectively underline part of an iMessage with MFMessage in Swift?

Thanks!

Comment: There is nothing built into the Firebase SDK for generating unique IDs with only numbers. But you could easily implement a similar algorithm using only numbers. See [this blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/02/the-2120-ways-to-ensure-unique_68.html) for an explanation of the push IDs and the (JavaScript) code for generating them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've need a similar option. When i create a new user; it will have a numberID which will be unique. I've tried **.push()** method which is for android, creates a uniqueID but with characters(letters) included. What i've done was something like this;

[image]

When i add a new user, i increment a value from different branch which is **User2Key** in this situation. And gave the value as key(parent) of newly added user.

When i delete or update a user, **User2Key** will be the same. If i add a new user then it will be incremented so every user will have uniqueID.

You can use a similar approach.

Hope this helps! Cheers!

Comment: Thanks, this is a good idea. I ended up creates a 'hash' from the key generated by firebase and using this to reference it.

Comment: can you share the details please

Comment: @emreE can you share how you are populating the user into the json tree please

Comment: Is it possible to write a sample code along with it